# Connection from Blackberry Q10 to tigerVNC server with "JAVA" failure

Tags: windows-7, java, vnc, blackberry

Details.

Blackberry Q10 Running bVNC PRO from the BBerry 10 App world.

Trying to connect to a tigerVNC server on a windows 7 (Home premium) computer (running on a lenovo idea pad z580)

I followed the instructions [here](http://iiordanov.blogspot.ca/2013/03/setting-up-tigervnc-for-secure.html).

Everything is done as he instructed, except the ports were configured in Norton 360 firewall instead of windows.

I've also opened the necessary ports on my modem/router.

Interestingly I can connect when my phone is connected via the same wifi network, however when I try to connect through the 4G verizon cell network I get this error every time.

[image]

I'm at a loss as to how to fix this. I've gone to canyouseeme.org and my ports are open and working fine. All setting have been double checked, e.g. all programs have the same port settings.

I'm hoping someone with know how can knock it out in 5 min.

Cheers

Bump or something. Still hoping someone knows how to fix this.

Comment: Dunno if comments bump the post but couldn't hurt to try.

Comment: No offence, but assuming its a problem with the BB side of things, there's not that many people these days who could reproduce it. I'd also wonder if other protocols work so that you can rule out something odd with verizon itself. Likewise, if you can teather, try it with a desktop client through your phone connection

Comment: Sorry, not that knowledgeable on these terms. What do you mean by other protocols? I can use blackberry link to access files remotely if that's what you mean by tether. It seems to be that connecting to the tiger VNC server over the verizon network is the only problem. Not to suggest that it is the network which is causing the problem, but it is exceptionally annoying because that's the one thing I was trying to do.